# Using strongly typed to make a dropdown menu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to let the user choose between different names in a dropdown menu, used from a folder on the computer. After they choose something they should be able to hit a button and then be able to edit the file. I am trying to avoid just using `ViewBag`.

My controller (Which is returning the right data into a `FormCollection` (Should it be a `FormCollection`?)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    FormCollection tableNames = TableNames();
    return View("Index",tableNames);
}

public FormCollection TableNames()
{
    String[] tableNamesPath = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Something\");
    FormCollection form = new FormCollection();

    foreach(String tableName in tableNamesPath)
    {
        form.Add(Path.GetFileName(tableName), Path.GetFileName(tableName));
    }

    return form;
}
```

Basicly I have nothing in my view, I have tried to use `Html.DropDownList` and `Html.DropDownListFor` (what is the difference?), but nothing seems to work. It might just be something silly I am missing, however I would be very happy for some help.

Comment: can we see your view code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, passing a [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is basicly wrong. The `FormCollection` is used to iterate through all post-values of a form.

I think your understanding of the basic approach of MVC is wrong. What you are trying to achive is editing a file. So your model should be a class called `FileModel`. The controller should look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Index", new FileModel());
}
```

This provides a view, bound to a new instance of `FileModel`. In the next step you want to select the file name of the file you want to edit. This means, your `FileModel` will get an property, called `FileName`, which get's assigned in the next step.

```
public class FileModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

We now have the *model* and the *controller*. Whats missing is the *view* part. This is the part that's actually responsible for user interaction. How to select a file is not the responsibility of the controller, so building up your drop-down should be done from the view. In my opinion the controller shouldn't even know that a drop-down is used to select a file name.

```
@model FileModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FileName)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FileName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FileName)
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Edit file" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

`DropDownListFor` simply tells the view, that the editor template for `FileName` is not a simple text box, but a drop-down. Now the last step is to fill in the options for the drop-down. Therefore we can use an overload of `DropDownListFor`.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FileName, 
    new SelectList(Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Something\"))
```

Now you should be able to select a file from your directory. This selection can be read in the controller from the post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FileModel model)
{
    var selectedFileName = model.FileName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work just as I wont to, however how do I removed the path and just show the name of the file?

Comment: Just take a look at [SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). It has an alternative constructor that accepts two strings, one identifying the key and the other representing the value. You can use the file paths as keys and the names values.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you using a view model. So start by defining one:

```
public class TableViewModel
{
    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller pass this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var tableNames = TableNames();
    return View("Index", tableNames);
}

public TableViewModel TableNames()
{
    String[] tableNamesPath = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Something\");
    TableViewModel model = new TableViewModel();
    model.Items = tableNamesPath.Select(item => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = Path.GetFileName(item),
        Text = Path.GetFileName(item),
    }).ToList();

    return model;
}
```

and then make your view strongly typed to this view model and you will be able to use the strongly typed DropDownListFor helper:

```
@model TableViewModel 

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItem, Model.Items)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am progress of trying off these solution, however I can't get it to work; In the SelectListItem, you add value and text with the tableName, where do you get that one from?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Use `item` instead. I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to present a list of file names in a dropdownlist. Let the user pick one, click a button and then present the contents of that file to the user for editing and saving.

If that is correct you should do a few things -

1. Pass a SelectList with the names of the files to the view and
   populate the dropdownlist.
2. Send back the selected item and another an Edit (GET) action method responsible for returning an edit view.
3. Post back the edited data to the Edit (POST) action method and save the changes.

If this is right, I'll post some code.